# Creating client certificate with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, certificates

I'm trying to configure a Client Authentication Certificate with OpenSSL with this command:

```
 openssl ca -config intermediate/openssl.cnf \
      -extensions usr_cert -days 7200 -notext -md sha256 \
      -in intermediate/csr/ADO-CSR0.csr \
      -out intermediate/certs/29-12-20/ADO-CSR0.cert.pem
```

But the certificate is empty:

```
ls -l intermediate/certs/29-12-20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  5 17:29 ADO-CSR0.cert.pem
```

I have this configuration:

```
[ ca ]
# `man ca`
default_ca = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
# Directory and file locations.
dir               = /root/ca/intermediate
certs             = $dir/certs
crl_dir           = $dir/crl
new_certs_dir     = $dir/newcerts
database          = $dir/index.txt
serial            = $dir/serial
RANDFILE          = $dir/private/.rand

# The root key and root certificate.
private_key       = $dir/private/intermediate.key.pem
certificate       = $dir/certs/intermediate.cert.pem

# For certificate revocation lists.
crlnumber         = $dir/crlnumber
crl               = $dir/crl/intermediate.crl.pem
crl_extensions    = crl_ext
default_crl_days  = 30

# SHA-1 is deprecated, so use SHA-2 instead.
default_md        = sha256

name_opt          = ca_default
cert_opt          = ca_default
default_days      = 375
preserve          = no
policy            = policy_loose

[ policy_strict ]
# The root CA should only sign intermediate certificates that match.
# See the POLICY FORMAT section of `man ca`.
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = match
organizationName        = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ policy_loose ]
# Allow the intermediate CA to sign a more diverse range of certificates.
# See the POLICY FORMAT section of the `ca` man page.
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ req ]
# Options for the `req` tool (`man req`).
default_bits        = 2048
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
string_mask         = utf8only

# SHA-1 is deprecated, so use SHA-2 instead.
default_md          = sha256

# Extension to add when the -x509 option is used.
x509_extensions     = v3_ca

[ req_distinguished_name ]
# See <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request>.
countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name
localityName                    = Locality Name
0.organizationName              = Organization Name
organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name
commonName                      = Common Name
emailAddress                    = Email Address

# Optionally, specify some defaults.
countryName_default             = DO
stateOrProvinceName_default     = Santo Domingo
localityName_default            =
0.organizationName_default      = Altice Dominicana
#organizationalUnitName_default =
#emailAddress_default           =

[ v3_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ v3_intermediate_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical intermediate CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ usr_cert ]
# Extensions for client certificates (`man x509v3_config`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = client, email
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Client Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, emailProtection

[ server_cert ]
# Extensions for server certificates (`man x509v3_config`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = server
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer:always
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth

[ crl_ext ]
# Extension for CRLs (`man x509v3_config`).
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ ocsp ]
# Extension for OCSP signing certificates (`man ocsp`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = critical, OCSPSigning
```

Can you help me?
Regards,
Ronald

Comment: While you posted the command you ran to generate that empty certificate file, you left out and the output from it, including any and all error messages.  In my experience, OpenSSL emits error messages when things like this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need to generate a key first or have it already generated and then use this command:

```
openssl req -out domain.csr -key /path/to/the/key/domain.key -new -sha256 -config openssl.cnf
```

Then you need to sign this domain.csr for 12, 24 , 36 or more months.

Then just

```
mv domain.csr domain.crt
```

After that you need to combine the Root and intermediate key and the domain domain.csr file into one.

I mean that you need to copy the content of all three files and put it into the file certificate.crt

**The order of copied certs is important!**

- First goes Domain cert -> domain.crt
- Second goes Intermediate cert 1 above domain -> intermediate.crt
- Third goes Intermediate cert 2 above that and so on
- Fourth goes (at the end of file) the Root cert -> root.crt

If you have the Root and Intermediate certificates in cer format (cer extension) you can convert them to crt this way:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in intermediate.cer -out intermediate.crt
openssl x509 -inform DER -in root.cer -out root.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you install a Windows version OpenVPN, and check the introduction to generate CA, server.crt server.key, etc using the tools it wraps on OpenSSL.